# Angular Material Sidenav - measure content size when sidenav width changes

Tags: angular, angular-material

How is it possible to correctly measure the width of the sidenav content after the sidenav width changed.

See stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav-collapse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html

Steps to reproduce:

- Click Button "Toggle sidenav content size" -> sidenav content width changes
- Calculated size in the orange box is not correct

[image]

The sidenav uses autoSize. See more here in the Sidenav API: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

I disabled animations by adding `NoopAnimationsModule`.
With animations enabled it becomes worse. Then the the calulation is also wrong when clicking "Toggle sidenav" in the example.

Here is another example which simulates the sidenav thing, but without the Material sidenav:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simulate-sidenav?file=src/app/app.component.ts

It works as expected. That's why I think there is something special about the Material Sidenav. Just what?

Comment: Don't have an answer for you but I did notice that if I add 100ms to the timeout, the correct values show. https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav-collapse-x4rzkq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: You are right, it looks like a timing issue. Sadly it is not an option to wait.
Also the duration of the necessary delay seems to depend on the CPU too :(

Comment: To me it looks like the delay is coming from here: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/sidenav/drawer.ts#L648-L653

_doCheckSubject emits when changeDetection is running and when autoSize is true (see here: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/sidenav/drawer.ts#L728)